# Python regex match any number of digits not immediately followed by period

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of multi-row strings. I want to match first rows of those strings if they start with a variable number of digits NOT immediately followed by a period.

For example, a list might be

```py
list = ["42. blabla \n foo", "42 blabla \n foo", "422. blabla \n foo"]
```

and my desired output would be `42 blabla`.

This code

```py
import re 

list = ["42. blabla \n foo", "42 blabla \n foo", "422. blabla \n foo"]

regex_header = re.compile("^[0-9]+(?!\.).*\n")

for str in list:
    print(re.findall(regex_header, str))
```

outputs

```
['42. blabla \n']
['42 blabla \n']
['422. blabla \n']
```

This one works only with exactly two digits in the beginning of the string:

```py
import re 

list = ["42. blabla \n foo", "42 blabla \n foo", "422. blabla \n foo"]

regex_header = re.compile("^[0-9]{2}(?!\.).*\n")

for str in list:
    print(re.findall(regex_header, str))
```

Output:

```
[]
['42 blabla \n']
['422. blabla \n']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `(?![.\d])` lookahead:

```
r"^\d+(?![.\d])"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ghNxI6/2). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?![.\d])` - no dot and any other digits are allowed to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TQNKMj):

```
import re 
l = ["42. blabla \n foo", "42 blabla \n foo", "422. blabla \n foo"]
regex_header = re.compile(r"^[0-9]+(?![.\d])")
for s in l:
    if (regex_header.search(s)):
        print(s)
# => "42 blabla \n foo"
```

Comment: Just wondering re the `.` inside the `[ ]` -- do we not need to escape it here to `\.`? I don't quite understand why `\d` works as expected in the brackets, while things seem to be different for the `.`? Thanks!

Comment: @patrick Inside a character class, only ``\``, `-`, `^` and `]` should be escaped. The rest is treated as literal chars. `[.]` = `r'\.'`. See [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400316/3832970)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this might be what we might want to output:

```
import re 

list = ["42. blabla \n foo", "42 blabla \n foo", "422. blabla \n foo"]

regex_header = re.compile("^[0-9]+(?!\.)\D*$")

for str in list:
    print(re.findall(regex_header, str))
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FQDJPs/1/)

Comment: Perfect -- this works as desired, and replacing ```$``` with ```\n``` will return only the first row.

Comment: EDIT: this works as desired, unless the line contains digits further away from the beginning (e.g. if we replace the second string in list with ```"42 blabla 00 \n foo"```).